# Custom form validation vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on pure vanilla javascript form validation no third party plugin. When I started the coding it was going more than 40 lines for just validating 4 fields is that possible can we make short and sweet few lines code validation using javascript. And in onfocus of the text field i want to hide the error class and back to normal when i type the values it has to show the black text in color.

Actually currently I am working on one form page it has more than 20 fields if i started coding for validation my god it was going so many numbr of line. :)

Currently I am using the below one

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" id="usr_name" name="usr_name" placeholder="User Name"/>
<input type="text" id="fst_name" name="fst_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
<input type="text" id="lst_name" name="lst_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<input type="text" id="mdl_name" name="mdl_name" placeholder="Middle Name"/>
<button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
```

Javascript code

```
function validate(){
    //alert("check");
    var uname = document.getElementById("usr_name");
    var fname = document.getElementById("fst_name");
    var lname = document.getElementById("lst_name");

    var mname = document.getElementById("mdl_name");

    if(uname.value.length <= 0){
        uname.placeholder = "kindly enter Uname";
        uname.classList.add("err");
    }
}
```

Here is the CSS.

```
.err{
    border:1px solid red;
    color:red;
}
.onfcs{
    border:0px solid red;
    color:black;
 }
```

Here is the [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/3zg6528c/)

Please help me.

Comment: You need to specify what parameters you want your validation to follow. What is valid input, and what isn't? You need to outline this for us first.

Comment: Keep it generic. From what I see all fields are required and must be strings. So extract general function for that and then call it for all fields.

Comment: Why recreate the wheel when the browser has it built in by default? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Comment: guys any example please

Comment: You have to have something tho. We can't just make up validation for you. You need to at least try. What is it you want to do? I know its validate...but how....ie: names can only contain 20 characters...etc

Comment: Hi @Carine actually it doesn't have in detail validation but it has all fields are mandatory

Comment: then just add the `required` attribute to the input element. Just like @epascarello pointed

Comment: Yes, what @anurupr said

Comment: but my Concern is the required attribute won't work on ie8 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="usr_name" class="validate" name="usr_name" placeholder="User Name"/>
<input type="text" id="fst_name" class="validate" name="fst_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
<input type="text" id="lst_name" class="validate" name="lst_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<input type="text" id="mdl_name" class="validate" name="mdl_name" placeholder="Middle Name"/>
<button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
function validate(){    

  // get all the inputs that have the validate class in it
  // this requires the input to have a class name valled validate
  var validateElements = document.getElementsByClassName("validate");


  // Get all the inputs 
  // This code is required because the output 
  // from 'document.getElementsByClassName' is not fit to the current needs

  // console.log("validateElements",validateElements); 
  // Uncomment the previous line to see the output of the 
  // 'document.getElementsByClassName' function

  var inputs = Array.prototype.filter.call(validateElements,
  function(element){
    return element.nodeName === 'INPUT';
  });

  // Loop through the inputs to be validated

  for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i ++ ){
    var input = inputs[i];
    if(input.value.length == 0){
        // generic placeholder
        input.placeholder = "kindly enter value";
        // error class
        input.classList.add("err");
        // The following is required if you want the validation to stop
        // once an invalid input is found
        // focus on the input [ optional ]
        //input.focus();
        // break the loop [ optional ]
        //break;
    }
  }    
}
```

[Update JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3zg6528c/1/)

Comment: hi @anurupr thanks for the code and your effort but it was not validating for all the fields :(

Comment: if you remove the input.focus and break statement , it will validate all the fields. Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you so much is that possible can i give different place holder value for all the fields :)

Comment: So where I can give the onfocus class in the fields validation on the javascript code or in the css iteself

Comment: i dont understand. what do you mean by onfocus class?

Comment: means when i start enter the value in fields addevent listner has to remove my cureent css which is red color

Comment: you should add that in the function which is fired when the document is loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86704/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-anurupr).

Comment: hi @anurupr one small query can i add multiple placeholder value instead of having "kindly enter value"